# Plotting the radiation pattern of a half-wave dipole antenna with a frequency of 144 MHz in MATLAB

Tags: antenna, matlab, radiation, code, dipole

I need to plot the radiation pattern of a half-wave dipole antenna with a frequency of 144 Mhz in MATLAB but I don't know the code, can someone please help me?

Comment: Do you mean code to run an animation as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna#Half-wave_dipole)? (I'm not a Matlab user, but I believe additional details about your exact goals would help others who are.)

Comment: Code to show like this https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f4/RadPatt-dB.png

Comment: That will help others who know Matlab. Thanks. Were it me, I'd be using *Glowscript.org* or *Trinket.io* to do something like this.)